# How to Inflate new layout inside cardview dynamically

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate the second XML inside cardview dynamically, but it throws null pointer exception.When I am trying to do hard code(by including directly inside card view layout) it works well.Is there any other way to inflate new XML dynamically?

CardView Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/room_detail_cards"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/room_detail_Linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/module_type_5"/>
        <!--<include layout="@layout/module_type_3"/>-->
        <!--<It Works well when i hard code the layout here/>-->

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecyclerAdapter.java(onCreateViewHolder)

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    layout= (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.room_detail_Linear_layout);
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.module_type_3, layout, false);
   layout.addView(itemView);             //NULL Pointer Exception occurs here
    View itemView1 = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.room_detail_card_view, null, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView1);
}
```

First layout XML(module_type_5)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:hint="module"
        android:id="@+id/module_5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Second XML Layout(module_type_3)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:hint="module"
        android:id="@+id/module_5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/add"
            android:id="@+id/switch_3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `view id` before inflating it at here:

```
layout= (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.room_detail_Linear_layout);
```

That's why layout is `null`.

Use `onCreateViewHolder` to return an instance of `ViewHolder` and perform all assignments in the view holder.

Something like this would work:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.room_detail_card_view, parent, false));
}
```

And then in your `ViewHolder` class:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}
```

And finally data binding in `onBindViewHolder`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText("some data")
}
```

Comment: Firstly i tried for onBindViewHolder to hold images but it didn't works for me ,thats why i tried to inflate whole layout inside cardView.

Comment: `onBindViewHolder` will work. If your not using it, then `RecyclerView` won't work properly. BTW `onCreateViewHolder` is called only once, so data won't get updated.